# AutoComplete from SQL Server DB using C# in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I try AutoComplete dropdown using C# code. Can I do without using AJAX. Or must use AJAX. How could I do? 
Can I use like that?

```
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey) 
{ ... }
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188442/whats-a-good-ajax-autocomplete-plugin-for-jquery

Answer (score 0):

you must use `Ajax` because without it you will reload your page for every key stroke. You can use `JQuery plugin` called `Autocomplete` or make your `Ajax` call.

you can find `autocomplete` here  http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete